# PHPInfo Wrong Date

Tags: php, date

Using PHP echoing the date correctly displays: "2012-01-04 11:04:07"

However, at the top of my phpinfo file, I have:

"System Linux server1.domain.com #1 SMP Tue Jun 21 10:29:24 EDT 2011 i686"

The date is showing Jun 21st instead of Jan 4th?

I am running Ubuntu and PHP 5.3.2.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question? What date do you want to display?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not the system time, that's a part of your kernel version (the time your OS's kernel was *made*). Nothing to be worried about (except perhaps check if that's an up-to-date kernel; if you're not administering the computer, don't worry about it).

If you can run system commands, you can get this by running `uname -a`. The output on my box:

```
Linux xyzzy 3.0.0-13-server #22-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 2 15:09:08 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This only means that the kernel was *built* two months ago - this has no bearing on current time (only in the sense of "how old is the core of my OS?").

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [your time zone settings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and make sure PHP has the same timezone setting as your server.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in phpInfo() output is not the current date afair.
Probably it is the date, when the server was set up or s.th. like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP timezone is likely set in your php.ini file:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =
```

Change this setting to be correct, and your PHP processes should return correctly.